# Python urlopen error

Tags: python, python-2.5, urlopen

I've just bought synology NAS (DS213J) and I am trying to run a python script on it.

**My python script:**

```
  1 #!/opt/bin/python
  2
  3 import urllib
  4 response = urllib.urlopen('http://google.com')
  5 html = response.read()
  6 print html
```

**when I run this script, I've got this output**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bin/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = urllib.urlopen('http://google.com')
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/urllib.py", line 82, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/urllib.py", line 190, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/urllib.py", line 272, in open_http
    import httplib
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 70, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/tempfile.py", line 33, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/random.py", line 58, in <module>
    SG_MAGICCONST = 1.0 + _log(4.5)
OverflowError: math range error
```

I also tried use urllib2 with no success.

**Script:**

```
  1 #!/opt/bin/python
  2
  3 import urllib2
  4 response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
  5 html = response.read()
  6 print html
```

**console output**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bin/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 92, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 70, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/tempfile.py", line 33, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/opt/lib/python2.5/random.py", line 58, in <module>
    SG_MAGICCONST = 1.0 + _log(4.5)
OverflowError: math range error
```

I have no idea what these errors mean; I've googled some with no success. The script above is part of a larger script to download subtitles for movies (I've just took error part from the bigger script and posted here).

I wrote that this script is running on synology DS213j, because I think that may be something with python installation. Generally I had problem with installing `ipkg` for my synylogy. I ended up with [this](https://github.com/trepmag/ds213j-optware-bootstrap/blob/master/README.md) tutorial. After installing bootstrap from the tutorial, I just run `ipkg install python` and package was installed successfully. My python version is `Python 2.5.6`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in  `#!/opt/bin/python`, run `which python` in order to figure out what is your python binary full path is.

As you can see your list of are ok:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> response = urllib.urlopen('http://google.com')
>>> html = response.read()
>>> print html
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="iw" dir="rtl"><head><meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title>[...]</body></html>
```

---

I think you should **use python 2.7** or [follow](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

Using `ipkg`:

```
ipkg update
ipkg install python27
```

`python2.7` will start the python interpreter.

Comment: hi, running 'which python' I've got '/opt/bin/python'.

Comment: your python is broken. try to run the commands from the shell, enter into python, by `$python` and run the commands.

Comment: yeah, that was something with 2.5 python. I've just installed 2.7 and urlopen works fine. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @ArekWoźniak I suggest to stick with one package installer manager, and you should go with the most popular. good luck